# Error logging SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell

I am iterating through all the site collection in SharePoint Online, and do something. However, some sites are erring. I am trying to create a log file along with URL and Error message.

This logging is not working, appreciate some help.

```
#Get credentials to connect
$Cred = Get-Credential
$ErrorFilePath = "CSV File Path"

#Parameters
$TenantAdmin = "Admin URL"
$SPAdmin = "Admin Account"

#Connect to Tenant admin
Connect-PnPOnline $TenantAdmin -Credentials $Cred

$Errordata = @()
Get-PnPTenantSite -Filter "Url -like '*/sites/*'" | ForEach-Object {
   try {
        Write-Host "Processing site : $($_.Url)......" -ForegroundColor "Yellow"
        $Connection = Connect-PnPOnline -ReturnConnection -Url $_.Url -Credentials $Cred
        Set-PnPTenantSite -Connection $Connection -url $_.Url -Owners $SPAdmin
        Write-Host "`t$SPAdmin is added to site collection admin" -ForegroundColor "DarkBlue"
        Remove-PnPSiteCollectionAdmin -Connection $Connection -Owners $SPAdmin
        Write-Host "`t$SPAdmin is removed from site collection admin" -ForegroundColor "White"
        
        If ($null -ne $_.Exception.Message) {
            $Errordata += [PSCustomObject][Ordered]@{
                    SiteURL = $_.Url                
                }
        }
   }

   catch {
        write-host -ForegroundColor "Red" "`tError:" $_.Exception.Message
        $Errordata | Add-Member -Name 'Error' -MemberType NoteProperty -Value $_.Exception.Message
   }
}
$Errordata | Export-Csv -Path $ErrorFilePath -Append`
```

Comment: Please provide any error messages that you receive.

Comment: Thanks Callum - I managed to fix moment ago. PS Custom Object should be within Catch block with out the if condition.